# Assign album artwork with mutagen mac vs. pc

Tags: python, mutagen

I am trying to assign a picture to a song, and I have some code that works on mac, but not on PC.

> from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
>
> from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC, error
>
> from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
>
> def image_assigner(self):
>
> ```
>    song = MP3(self.file, ID3=ID3)
>
>    # add ID3 tag if it doesn't exist
>    try:
>        song.add_tags()
>    except error:
>        print "we got an image error"
>        pass
>
>    song.tags.add(
>        APIC(
>            encoding=3, 
>            mime='image/jpeg', 
>            type=2, 
>            desc=u'Cover',
>            data=open('example.JPG', 'rb').read()
>        )
>    )
>    song.save()
> ```

So on Mac, this code works, but when I try it on my PC, it won't. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

*Edit*
So, after doing some more research, I figured out that this code does save the album artwork to the mp3 file on Mac as well as Windows, but it saves it in ID3v2.4, which Mac can read, but Windows can't read, so it appeared like it didn't save it on Windows. It appears that using the v1=2 option in the mutagen save function should save the tags in ID3v1 (see the Oct. 4th post on [this](https://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial) page). It seems to work if I update the tags for album, artist, title, etc., but when I do it for album artwork, it still doesn't show up in Windows explorer. Does anybody have experience in this area and could shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add information regarding what exactly it is that doesn't work?

Comment: It won't assign the image to the file. When I do it in mac, it assigns the image to the mp3 file, and when I do it in windows, it doesn't. It doesn't throw any errors or anything, but it just doesn't do what its supposed to.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah unfortunately `Windows` doesn't support that version.  Instead of just saving it in `ID3v1` try saving it in `ID3v3` and `ID3v1`.  I use this in my programs and it works great in `Windows 8` and `OSX`.

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC, error, TRCK, TIT2, TPE1, TALB, TDRC, TCON

audio = MP3([PATH_TO_FILE], ID3=ID3)
audio.tags.delete([PATH_TO_FILE], delete_v1=True, delete_v2=True)
audio.tags.add(
    APIC(
        encoding=3,
        mime='image/jpeg',
        type=3,
        desc=u'Cover',
        data=open([PATH_TO_COVER_IMAGE], 'rb').read()
    )
)
audio.save([PATH_TO_FILE], v2_version=3, v1=2)
```